# How to handle element in parent id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show a content in an increase id ( #showcp_ ) when click the id ( #coupon_click_ ) I use php for increase the value of ids, and I just want to show content in parent id ( #cp_box_ ), how to solve this ?

```
<div class="row cp_box" >
    <?php 
    $counter = -1;
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'showposts' => 3,
        'cat' => 6,
    );
    ?>
    <?php $getposts = new WP_query($args); ?>
    <?php global $wp_query; $wp_query->in_the_loop = true; ?>
    <?php while ($getposts->have_posts()) : $getposts->the_post(); $counter++ ?>

        <div id="cp_box_<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="col large-4" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);position:relative;">
            <ul class="time_cp">
                <li class="time-begin">Time begin:  </li>
                <li class="time-end">Expired: </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="coupon_wrap">
                <a id="coupon_click_<?php echo $counter; ?>"  href="#" target="_blank">View coupon</a>
                <p  id="showcp_<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="cp_show" style="display:none;">Coupon code</p>
                <a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[id^='coupon_click_']").click(function() {
            $("[id^='showcp_']").show();
            $("[id^='coupon_click_']").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily using the correct `this` context here like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^='coupon_click_']").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".coupon_wrap").find("[id^='showcp_']").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

- `$(this).closest(".coupon_wrap")` will find the closest parent div with class `.coupon_wrap` to the clicked `coupon_click_` link.
- Then it will find the `showcp_` element inside that div and show it.
- And finally using `$(this).hide()` we simply hide the clicked `coupon_click_` element instead of hiding all the elements where id starts with `coupon_click_`.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) after 5 mins to help future users too. Thanks!